# Golang - Cannot access map in []interface{}

Tags: json, dictionary, go, interface

I have used `json.Unmarshal` and extracted json content. I then managed to get one layer deeper into the `[]interface{}` by using the following code:

```
        response, err := http.Get("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=2B2A0C37AC20B5DC2234E579A2ABB11C&steamids=76561198132612090")
        content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        defer response.Body.Close()
        if err != nil {
            panic(0)
        }

        var decoded map[string]interface{}
        if err := json.Unmarshal(content, &decoded); err != nil {
            panic(0)
        }

        players := decoded["response"].(map[string]interface{})["players"]
        if err != nil {
            panic(0)
        }
```

Variable players' type is `[]interface {}` and content is `[map[personaname:Acidic]]`.

How do I access this map? I've tried `players["personaname"]` but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: could you post the expected JSON content? I'm afraid you asserted wrong thing into wrong type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Players is a JSON array. Thus you have to convert it to a slice of interface.

Then you can access any element of the slice and casting it to a `map[string]interface{}` type.

Here's the working example

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=2B2A0C37AC20B5DC2234E579A2ABB11C&steamids=76561198132612090")
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(0)
    }

    var decoded map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(content, &decoded); err != nil {
        panic(0)
    }

    players := decoded["response"].(map[string]interface{})["players"]
    if err != nil {
        panic(0)
    }

    sliceOfPlayers := players.([]interface{})
    fmt.Println((sliceOfPlayers[0].(map[string]interface{}))["personaname"])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining a struct type with the expected schema will make your life easier when you want to get the data from it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

//import "net/http"
//import "io/ioutil"
import "encoding/json"

// you don't need to define everything, only what you need
type Player struct {
    Steamid                  string
    Communityvisibilitystate int
    Personaname              string
    Lastlogoff               int64 // time.Unix(Lastlogoff, 0)
    Profileurl               string
    Avatar                   string
    Avatarmedium             string
    Avatarfull               string
    Personastate             int
    Realname                 string
    Primaryclanid            string
    Timecreated              int64 // time.Unix(Timecreated, 0)
    Personastateflags        int
    //Loccountrycode           string // e.g. if you don't need this
}

func main() {
    /*response, err := http.Get("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=2B2A0C37AC20B5DC2234E579A2ABB11C&steamids=76561198132612090")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    content, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    defer response.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(0)
    }*/
    content := []byte(`{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198132612090",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "Acidic",
                "lastlogoff": 1459489924,
                "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/ari9/",
                "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bc/bc50a4065c31c606e51dfad329341b2d1f1ac4d3.jpg",
                "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bc/bc50a4065c31c606e51dfad329341b2d1f1ac4d3_medium.jpg",
                "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/bc/bc50a4065c31c606e51dfad329341b2d1f1ac4d3_full.jpg",
                "personastate": 3,
                "realname": "Ari Seyhun",
                "primaryclanid": "103582791440552060",
                "timecreated": 1397199406,
                "personastateflags": 0,
                "loccountrycode": "TR"
            }
        ]

    }
}`)

    var decoded struct {
        Response struct {
            Players []Player
        }
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(content, &decoded); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", decoded.Response.Players)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/gVPRwLFunF

You can also create a new named type from `time.Time` for `Timecreated` and `Lastlogoff` with its own `UnmarshalJSON` function, and immediately convert it to `time.Time` using `time.Unix()`

Comment: I personally prefer to create structs to strongly type my data, though it is more work.

Comment: There are tools now to auto generate struct types from json and it's not that hard to Google for them. It shouldn't take long to come to understand map[string]interface{} is the wrong type of laziness. The interface{} object you end up with is so much more difficult to deal with.